# Reference external script in JavaScript Azure Function code

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-functions

### Goal

I would like a specific JavaScript file to be referenced by multiple JavaScript Azure Functions that are managed by different users in different Azure subscriptions. All the subscriptions are within an enterprise subscription. I would also like these multiple users to be able to alter this single-sourced file.

### Proposed solution

My best guess on how to accomplish this is to store the file in a public GitHub repository and have each Function reference it.

### Problem

Referencing an external script (in my case, the script hosted in GitHub) in standard ways (as I understand them) does not seem to work when implemented in a JavaScript Azure Function.

### Code

**Structure:**

```
var abc = require('<external reference>');
```

**Sample external JS file:**

```
https://github.com/<username>/<repo>/blob/master/file.js
```

### Failed attempts

There seem to be many outdated methods documented on SO (e.g., rawgit) but I am looking at the answers last edited in 2018.

- `https://github.com/<username>/<repo>/blob/master/file.js`
- `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<username>/<repo>/master/file.js`
- `http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/<username>/<repo>/file.js`

### Alternatives

I know that in the case that multiple Functions within a single Azure Function (and therefore within the same Azure subscription) can reference a centrally managed file by:

- Placing it in a `Shared` folder, adding `"watchDirectories": [ "Shared" ]` to `host.json`, and referencing it with `require('../Shared/file.js')`
- Referencing code in one Function from another (e.g., in Function-2 I can use `require('../Function-1/file.js')`)

However, unless I misunderstand, neither meets the requirements that the Functions can reside in different Functions in different Azure subscriptions.

I am new to JS. Thank you for any guidance. There may be other ways to satisfy these requirements that I am not thinking of.

Comment: According to the rawgit [website](http://rawgit.com), it's no longer available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to `require` the js files in the typical sense from inside a function, as `require` uses the filesystem to resolve files, which wouldn't really exist inside of a function. If the js you want to run is available on github you could download the source from github. And use the JS `Function` constructor to run the create a function you can call. Very roughly it might look something like:

```
let myfunc;
fetchCodeToRun().then(codeString=>myfunc=new Function(codeString)); //untested
```

Please note that I'm not specifically too familiar with Azure, and I only have a tiny amount of experience with serverless infrastructure so it's very possible that there's a better way of accomplishing this.

Function constructor docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function